# In React can properties of grandparents be accessed by a grandchild without the parent passing it down?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I am currently working on my first React project and I came into an issue with passing data between components. I am using this libraries calendar widget in order to style different days depending on the selected item in a list.

https://github.com/vazco/meteor-universe-react-widgets

I have four interacting components that are within my tree in this structure:

```
-----A-----
|         |
C         B
|
|
D
```

I am currently storing the data of a selected item in a list (Component B) from my top level component (Component A). The component I want to pass the data to is Component D. What I want to do is create a state and pass the value to C and then on to D. Unfortunately, C is the calendar component from the library which I cant really manipulate.

As I need the object generated by the selection in B to be accessed by D without being able to manipulate C, Is there a way to pass values over the head of a child component?

Code snippets:

How Component C (calendar) is called in A, while also passing in component D (dayComponent).

```
<Calendar dayComponent={DayComponent}/>;
```

The calendar component declaration & import

```
System.import('{universe:react-widgets}').then(ReactWidgets => {

    Calendar = ReactWidgets.Calendar;
});
```

The Day component returns styling for the calendar days.

```
 DayComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var date = this.props.date
      , style = { backgroundColor: date < new Date() && '#F57B7B' }

    return (<div style={style}>
        {this.props.label}
      </div>);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not props, no. That's not how React works. React send props in a top-down direction, with parents passing properties to their children. The idea is that a component shouldn't care where it's rendered, or by what, as long as the props set for it are valid.

That being said, there *is* a facility for "punching a hole" (so to speak) in your component tree, to allow a child component to access data from higher up in the tree: [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

However, Context is generally regarded to be an advanced feature, and *only* used in very specific situations where another solution just isn't viable.

From the docs page:

> **Note:** Context is an advanced and experimental feature. The API is likely to change in future releases. Most applications will never need
>   to use context. Especially if you are just getting started with React,
>   you likely do not want to use context. Using context will make your
>   code harder to understand because it makes the data flow less clear.
>   It is similar to using global variables to pass state through your
>   application. If you have to use context, use it sparingly.

The idea is that in your top level component you define what Context properties you want to make available, and then a method to return the Context data:

```
class TopComponent extends Component {
  childContextTypes: {
    color: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {color: "purple"};
  },
  ..
}
```

And then in a child component somewhere down the tree, you tell that component which Context properties you want access to:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  contextTypes: {
    color: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  ...
}
```

And then those properties will be accessible via `this.context` property (`this.context.color` for instance).

Comment: Thanks for that, seems perfect for what I need. I'll try this out and then try find a way to do it the proper way. May just have to drop the library. Thanks again. Clear answer.